# How to include authors (users) in the results for the native WordPress search?

Tags: wordpress, search

Does anyone knows a way to include authors as part of the search results in the native wordpress theme without plugins?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You could use the code snippet [you find here](https://gist.github.com/danielbachhuber/7126249), and place it into your `functions.php` - or create your own plugin based on it.

Comment: Any idea on how to include custom fields?

Comment: @Adeerlike ACF? Not tested, but I would give this a shot: https://wordpress.org/plugins/acf-better-search/

Comment: thank you. However this doesn't do it for some reason..